# If you take a standard representation of a symmetric group, take an alternating tensor power of it, what groups appear as stabilizers of vectors?

Tags: gr.group-theory, co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory

I'm particularly interested in the case $\Lambda^3 \mathbb{F}_3^n$, and specifically, just stabilizers of vectors that satisfy the two conditions (i) there are no zero coordinates (in the basis induced from the standard basis of $\mathbb{F}_3^n$) and (ii) they are in the image of a map $(\mathbb{R}^n)^3 \to \Lambda^3 \mathbb{F}_3^n$ that I will now describe.

We start with the obvious map $(\mathbb{R}^n)^3 \to \Lambda^3 \mathbb{R}^n$. Then write our vector in the standard coordinates $\sum_{i < j < k} a_{ijk} e_i \wedge e_j \wedge e_k \in \Lambda^3 \mathbb{R}^n$ and then replace $a_{ijk}$ with $0 \in \mathbb{F}_3$ if it is 0, $1 \in \mathbb{F}_3$ if it is positive, and $-1 \in \mathbb{F}_3$ if it is negative.

I can calculate with GAP all stabilizers for n = 4, 5, and stabilizers for given vectors for n = 6, 7.

For n = 4 I get $\mathbb{Z} / 4, \mathbb{Z} / 3$, and $Alt(4)$, for n = 5 I get $1, \mathbb{Z} / 3$ and $\mathbb{Z} / 5$, and for n = 6 and 7 I can find cyclic groups of orders 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, and 1, 3 respectively.

It seems like the sort of problem that should have a solution....

Comment: Two observations: The standard representation does not permute coordinates (this is
the permutation representation which is given by the standard plus the trivial).

Secondly, alternate powers of the standard representation are exactly 
the $L-$shaped representations, at least in characteristic zero.
I do not know what happens to them in characteristic $3$.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the field has characteristic $\neq 2 $.

(1) Assume the vector is the standard basis vectors in wedge product with the standard basis in the standard permutation representation $V$, i.e., $v=v_{1}\wedge v_2\wedge \cdots \wedge v_r\in \Lambda^r V$. The any element in the stabilizer stabilizes the subset $\{ 1,\dots, r\}\subseteq \{1,\dots, n\}$ and its restriction to the subset $\{1,\dots, r\}$ is an even permutation and thus is an element in $A_r$. Thus the stabilizer is $A_r\times S_{n-r}$.
For other basis elements, simply replace $\{1, \dots, r\}$ by any subset $\{ i_1 < \dots < i_r\}$.

(2) If the vector is sum of a set of basis elements. Let $A\subseteq \{1, \dots, n\}$ is a subset of $r$ elements and $v_A$ be the basis elements discussed in (1). 
Hence $v=\sum_{s=1}^t v_{A_s}$. The the stabilizer consists of elements that stabilizers each $A_1, \dots, A_t$ and restricts to each is even, and multiplied by $\sigma \in S_n$ which defines a permutation of the above sets $A_1, \dots, A_r$. Now you know how to determine this group.

(3) For a general vector, write it as linear combination of the standard basis and group them so that they is a linear combination of elements of type (2) with distinct non-zero coefficients so that two different terms have common basis terms. The stabilizer is the intersection of the stabilizers described in (2). For $\mathbb{F}_3$. there are at most two such subgroups to intersect.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I agree with (1) but for (3) the situation is a bit more complicated. Write $e_{ijk} = e_i \wedge e_j \wedge e_k$. In $\Lambda^3 F^4$ (if char of $F$ is not 2) the stabilizer of $e_{123} + e_{124}$ is generated by $(3,4)$ and the stabilizer of $e_{234} + e_{134}$ is generated by $(1,2)$ but the stabilizer of $e_{123} + e_{124} - e_{234} - e_{134}$ is generated by $(1,3,4,2)$ which has nothing to do with the other two groups.


Answer (score 0):

I take back (3) (and partial (2) as well)! Let $C(r,n)$ be the set of all $r$-combinations of {$ 1,2, \dots, n$}, which has the natural order. $\wedge ^r(V)$ is a signed permutation representation of $ S_n$ with a basis {${ e_{A}| A\in C(r,n)\}$} such that $\sigma e_A=sign(\sigma(A))e_{\sigma(A)}$. I missed the sign in my (3).